# How come a flight is cheaper with an extra stop?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines

I found a flight from a smaller airport (A) to an intercontinental place (C) for a price of EUR 440. This flight has 1 stop at a city also not far from my home (B). The stop however is 26 hours.

So I searched for the flight going from point B to point C directly without the stop of 26 hours and the price is EUR 750. The price difference for **adding** 1 stop for the same flight is EUR 310 more.

I asked the airliner how this is possible but didn't get a clear answer. Thanks in advance.

Scenario:

A->B (26h)->C = EUR 440

B->C          = EUR 750

Comment: Hmmm, so no real cause like taxes or logistics but just because they can and people will pay the price for premium.

Comment: Offer and demand. People prefer direct flights, and are willing to pay more for it, so more is charged for it.